# Bootstrap Button styling changes when overflowed into a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, flask, overflow, bootstrap-5

I have a page designed in Bootstrap and am handling the overflow of my elements by using a scrollbar.
The buttons I use are styled to have round corners, but when enough elements are on the page that it overflows into a scroll bar, the rounded corners disappear and, while all my other styling elements are preserved, the buttons become boring rectangles. Is this just a property of `overflow-y: scroll` or can I avoid it? Here is my HTML:

```
       <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h6 class="text-white-50 mb-2 mx-auto">Your Ordered Playlist:</h6>
                    
                    <div class="scrol">
                    {%for i in rankings%}
                        <div class="row">
                        
                    <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist"/>
                        </div>
                    {%endfor%}
                    
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

And my relevant CSS:

```
.scrol {
   height: 400px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }

 .align-items-center {
   align-items: center !important;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.btn {
    --bs-btn-padding-x: 0.75rem;
    --bs-btn-padding-y: 0.375rem;
    --bs-btn-font-family: ;
    --bs-btn-font-size: 1rem;
    --bs-btn-font-weight: 400;
    --bs-btn-line-height: 1.5;
    --bs-btn-color: #212529;
    --bs-btn-bg: transparent;
    --bs-btn-border-width: 1px;
    --bs-btn-border-color: transparent;
    --bs-btn-border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --bs-btn-hover-border-color: transparent;
    --bs-btn-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    --bs-btn-disabled-opacity: 0.65;
    --bs-btn-focus-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(var(--bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb), .5);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: var(--bs-btn-padding-y) var(--bs-btn-padding-x);
    font-family: var(--bs-btn-font-family);
    font-size: var(--bs-btn-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--bs-btn-font-weight);
    line-height: var(--bs-btn-line-height);
    color: var(--bs-btn-color);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    border: var(--bs-btn-border-width) solid var(--bs-btn-border-color);
    border-radius: var(--bs-btn-border-radius);
    background-color: var(--bs-btn-bg);
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }

.btn-primary {
  --bs-btn-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-bg: #64a19d;
  --bs-btn-border-color: #64a19d;
  --bs-btn-hover-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: #558985;
  --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #50817e;
  --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: 123, 175, 172;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-active-bg: #50817e;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #4b7976;
  --bs-btn-active-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  --bs-btn-disabled-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-disabled-bg: #64a19d;
  --bs-btn-disabled-border-color: #64a19d;
}
```

I have adjusted the width of the buttons and tried different methods of `overflow`. I also got rid of scroll altogether, since my buttons look normal when I do that, but didn't like how much space it could take up on the page, so I am excluding that as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button radius and styling are still there, but not visible, because of negative margins of the `row`, so add `container` class to `scrol` container to counteract it, as class `row` must be a child of a `container` (also maybe better use `overflow-y: auto`).

```
  <div class="container scrol">
    <div class="row">
```

*original code*:

```
  <div class="container scrol">
    {%for i in rankings%}
        <div class="row">
            <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist"/>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

*Note: as content should then go in `col`, so maybe wrap `input`s into a `col` container, to make sure there are no further style side effects.*

Alternatively, depending on your layout, you could remove `row` class from `scrol` children, move it on some parent container, for example the one following `container`, and then you could use `col`s for breakpoints:

```
<div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h6 class="text-white-50 mb-2 mx-auto">Your Ordered Playlist:</h6>
            <div class="scrol">
                <div class="">
```

docs:

> **Rows are wrappers for columns.** Each column has horizontal padding
> (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
> is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins to ensure the
> content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.
>
> [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

demo (add `container` to `scrol`):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .scrol {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  .align-items-center {
    align-items: center !important;
  }
  
  .justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
  
  .btn {
    --bs-btn-padding-x: 0.75rem;
    --bs-btn-padding-y: 0.375rem;
    --bs-btn-font-family: ;
    --bs-btn-font-size: 1rem;
    --bs-btn-font-weight: 400;
    --bs-btn-line-height: 1.5;
    --bs-btn-color: #212529;
    --bs-btn-bg: transparent;
    --bs-btn-border-width: 1px;
    --bs-btn-border-color: transparent;
    --bs-btn-border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --bs-btn-hover-border-color: transparent;
    --bs-btn-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    --bs-btn-disabled-opacity: 0.65;
    --bs-btn-focus-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(var(--bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb), .5);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: var(--bs-btn-padding-y) var(--bs-btn-padding-x);
    font-family: var(--bs-btn-font-family);
    font-size: var(--bs-btn-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--bs-btn-font-weight);
    line-height: var(--bs-btn-line-height);
    color: var(--bs-btn-color);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: var(--bs-btn-border-width) solid var(--bs-btn-border-color);
    border-radius: var(--bs-btn-border-radius);
    background-color: var(--bs-btn-bg);
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .btn-primary {
    --bs-btn-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-bg: #64a19d;
    --bs-btn-border-color: #64a19d;
    --bs-btn-hover-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #558985;
    --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #50817e;
    --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: 123, 175, 172;
    --bs-btn-active-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #50817e;
    --bs-btn-active-border-color: #4b7976;
    --bs-btn-active-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    --bs-btn-disabled-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-disabled-bg: #64a19d;
    --bs-btn-disabled-border-color: #64a19d;
  }
</style>





<div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h6 class="text-white-50 mb-2 mx-auto">Your Ordered Playlist:</h6>

      <div class="container scrol">

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <input autocomplete="off" value="{{i}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-wrap" name="playlist" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```